# AVR assembly language - How do I store bits of data into memory

Tags: assembly, storage, increment, avr

What I'm trying to do is basically make a loop in AVR studio4 which writes hex numbers from 0 to 4F into consecutive memory locations. I'm using r16 to write the values and then store those values to memory and that just keeps going. Here's what I have so far:

```
.cseg
LDI r16, 0x00 ;Initialize the first value
st x, r16

loop:
inc r16 ;increments the counter by 1
st x, r16 ;stores the data into a memory location
brne loop


done: jmp done


.dseg
.org 200 
.db 0x50 ;reserves 50 bits of storage in memory
```

So what else do I have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `BRNE`, which will jump back to `loop` if the Zero flag is clear. But nothing you do in your loop will set the Zero flag when `r16` becomes 0x50. To achieve that you would use a comparison instruction:

```
CPI R16,0x50  ; compare R16 with the immediate 0x50
BRNE loop     ; loop if not equal
```

---

Another issue is that you say that you want stores the values 0x00..0x4F, but you're incrementing `r16` before you've stored it in memory, so the first value you'll be storing is 1. So you should switch the order between the `inc` and the `st`. <sup><sub>(**Edit:** I didn't notice that you were storing the first value before the loop. I still think the way I propose is better since it's less code)</sub></sup>
Also, you appear to be writing all values to the same address. Want you probably want is `st x+,r16  ; store indirect and post-increment x`.

To summarize:

```
loop:
st x+,r16     ; store indirect and post-increment x
inc r16       ; increments the counter by 1
cpi r16,0x50  ; have we reached beyond the range of numbers that we want to print? 
brne loop     ; if we haven't, loop again
```

---

The way you attempt to reserve space for your values also looks incorrect:

```
.db 0x50 ;reserves 50 bits of storage in memory
```

`.db 0x50` means you're reserving space for *a single byte* with the value 0x50. To reserve space for 0x50 bytes you should use `.byte 0x50`. Refer to [Atmel's documentation of the assembler directives](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_directives.html). And you might want to load the base address of those bytes into `x` before the loop.

Comment: And then at the end, do I want to clear the values out of r16?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "clear the values out of r16", or why you would need that(?).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined end condition for your loop (which is to compare whether your loop counter equals `0x4f`):

```
loop:
inc r16       ; increments the counter by 1
st x, r16     ; stores the data into a memory location
cpi r16, 0x4f ; check whether we have written all the bytes
brne loop
```